# Android: Unable to communicate in the broadcast receiver to MainActivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I am working on BroadcastReceiver. My code are as follows:

### `Settings2` class

```
public void set_notification_task()
    {
        Utilities.initParse(Settings2.this);
        get_notification_info();
    }

    public void get_notification_info()
    {
        ...
    }

    private void setAlarm_manager(Calendar c)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings2.this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);   
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Settings2.this, ALARM_RUEST, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    } 
}
```

### `AlarmBroadcastReceiver

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Settings2 setting_activity;

    public AlarmBroadcastReceiver() { }

    public AlarmBroadcastReceiver(Settings2 setting_Context){
        setting_activity =setting_Context;
    }

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
         //Acquire the lock
         wl.acquire();

         //You can do the processing here.
         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
         StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

         if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
          //Make sure this intent has been sent by the one-time timer button.
          msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
         }
         Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
         msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

         Toast.makeText(context, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         wl.release();  //Release the lock

         setting_activity.set_notification_task(); //line 49
     }
}
```

### Logcat:

```
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045): Process: com.abc.wmn, PID: 25045
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.abc.utilities.AlarmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.abc.wmn.Settings2.set_notification_task()' on a null object reference
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2739)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.abc.wmn.Settings2.set_notification_task()' on a null object reference
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at com.abc.utilities.AlarmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java:49)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732)
11-07 00:28:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(25045):    ... 8 more
```

### Question:

It got the above logcat problem: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.abc.utilities.AlarmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.abc.wmn.Settings2.set_notification_task()' on a null object reference`, how can this be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` being constructed?  Could you post that code please?

Comment: thanks for your reply. the code is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved as follows:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Settings2 setting_activity;

    public AlarmBroadcastReceiver() { }

    public AlarmBroadcastReceiver(Settings2 setting_Context){
        setting_activity =setting_Context;
    }

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
         //Acquire the lock
         wl.acquire();

         //You can do the processing here.
         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
         StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

         if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
          //Make sure this intent has been sent by the one-time timer button.
          msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
         }
         Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
         msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

         Toast.makeText(context, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         wl.release();  //Release the lock

         setting_activity = new Settings2();
         setting_activity.set_notification_task();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `setting_activity` is `null`, here:

```
setting_activity.set_notification_task();
```

This is because the `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` constructor which sets `setting_activity` will never be called.  Since a `PendingIntent` is being used to invoke the your broadcast, it will be the default constructor of `AlarmBroadcastReceiver`, not your custom constructor, which gets called when the broadcast is sent.  As a result, the `setting_activity` variable is never initialized, and thus the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

As Pathfinderelite says, you can't just access your Activity from your Receiver. What you can do, is make your activity available in the Receiver via dependency injection, or, more easily, by creating a static link in the Activity to the instance of itself. The Receiver can then get the instance, but it does need to check for null because there's no guarantee the Activity is available and not-null when onReceive gets called. (I apologize for not formatting, keyboard back quote is broken).